# How do I get the AccountId as a variable in a serverless.yml file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I want to build an ARN in my file dynamically, but I need to get my current AccountId. How can I access it as a variable?

For example:

```
example: arn:aws:states:${region}:${accountId}:stateMachine:${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}-example
```

What is the proper way to reference the current `region` and `accountId`?

Comment: The accepted answer is now outdated, this [native solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64867520/4056509) worked for me

Comment: I changed the accepted answer to be the native solution. scroll down to see it!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is now supported natively in Serverless Framework.

#### functions example

```yaml
  functions:
    hello:
      handler: my-function.handler
      environment:
        var: !Sub arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/*:*:*'
```

#### iam role example

```yaml
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - dynamodb:*
          Resource: !Sub arn:aws:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:table/${AWS::StackName}-*
```

See [Pseudo Parameters Reference](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#pseudo-parameters-reference) for the official docs.

Comment: This worked for me. This should be higher up since its a native solution without relying on plugins.

Comment: For those of you who try to use this solution, make sure to include the `!Sub` in the front.

Comment: Also see the [AWS CloudFormation Pseudo parameters reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html) in addition to the serverless docs link in the answer.

Answer (score 28):

This is now supported natively since version 2.3.0.

Just reference it via `${aws:accountId}`. You can also reference region via  `${aws:region}`. Documentation here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#referencing-aws-specific-variables

```yaml
service: new-service
provider: aws

functions:
  func1:
    name: function-1
    handler: handler.func1
    environment:
      ACCOUNT_ID: ${aws:accountId}
      REGION: ${aws:region}
```

Comment: Is this different than the accepted answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64867520/12958

Comment: the accepted answer uses the Cloudformation pseudo parameters reference* (`AWS::AccountId` w/ double colon) with the help of  `!Sub` function. My answer natively supports the `${aws:accountId}` but only supported on serverless version >= 2.3.0

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html

Comment: The use of the `!Sub` function in the previous answer is irrelevant. Using the updated `aws:accountId` is indeed better tho.

Comment: I was able to switch over the ones you mentioned, but ${aws:stackName} doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yeah... but... BIG but... doesn't work with serverless offline !!!

Answer (score 24):

There's a handy serverless plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-pseudo-parameters that adds the ability to reference aws parameters such as region and account id that i've just started using to much success.

Comment: I haven't vetted this plugin yet but this seems like the best answer to be honest, switched to be the correct answer.

Comment: You can also use !Ref to access them.

Comment: That package says that it is deprecated and supported natively in serverless framework now. I'm trying to figure out how to use it natively...

Comment: @Madeo, it works. Check out my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64867520/1495198

Comment: @Madeo, I have it working for an iam policy: `Resource: !Sub arn:aws:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:table/${AWS::StackName}-*`. You can see the full serverless.yml file here:
https://github.com/vivmaha/blog-server/blob/main/serverless.yml

Comment: @VivekMaharajh you might have two versions of serverless installed? one locally and one globally? might be worth double checking

Comment: @Madeo, so if you clone my repo and try `npm run sls -- package --stage dev`, it fails for you? SamJ's suggestion is promising as well, I assumed they meant to tell you that not me.

Answer (score 9):

Serverless itself cannot reference those variables since those are defined within CloudFormation, but not exposed in serverless.

If you need those in the resources section you can directly access them via "Ref"-call.

[AWS CloudFormation Pseudo-variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html)

If you need those variable as function environment variables, you can overwrite the serverless generated function code with CloudFormation code.

So to achieve this, you must modify you serverless.yml by the following pattern.

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
resources:
  Resources:
   HelloLambdaFunction:
     Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
     Properties:
       Environment:
         Variables:
           accountId:
             Ref: AWS::AccountId
           region:
             Ref: AWS::Region
           arn:
             Fn::Join:
               - ""
               - - "arn:aws:states:"
                 - Ref: AWS::Region
                 - ":"
                 - Ref: AWS::AccountId
                 - ":stateMachine:"
                 - ${self:service}
                 - "-"
                 - ${self:custom.stage}
                 - "-example"
```

Comment: Please note that this answer is outdated. This is indeed supported in serverless framework now as I explain in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64867520/1495198).

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT**: this question is probably outdated. Consider [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612499/how-do-i-get-the-accountid-as-a-variable-in-a-serverless-yml-file/42614780?noredirect=1#comment117899966_42614780) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612499/how-do-i-get-the-accountid-as-a-variable-in-a-serverless-yml-file/64867520#64867520).

---

AWS CloudFormation offers [some variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html) like `AWS::AccountId`and `AWS::Region`, but you can't use them in the **serverless.yml** file like `${AWS::AccountId}`. Those are not supported.

[@jens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42614604/1476885) is right. You must use the CloudFormation syntax. In the example below, I provide another way to use CloudFormation.

```
service: testing-aws-account-id

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs4.3
  region: us-east-1
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "iot:Publish"
      Resource: 'Fn::Join: ["", [ "aws:iot:", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" }, ":", { Ref: "AWS::AccountId" }, ":topic/foo" ]]'

functions:
  publishIot:
    handler: handler.publishIot
```

The line:

```
 Resource: 'Fn::Join: ["", [ "aws:iot:", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" }, ":", { Ref: "AWS::AccountId" }, ":topic/foo" ]]'
```

is the same of hard-coding the region and account id:

```
Resource: "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:1234567890:topic/foo"
```

Comment: Could that line be replaced with `Resource: '!Sub arn:aws:iot:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:topic/foo'` ?

Comment: @BamaPookie, I don't think so. It should work only if you add [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-pseudo-parameters).

Comment: I get `Partition "" is not valid for resource "arn::Join: ["", [ "arn:`

Comment: @BamaPookie you really helped me out here with this. This plugin is exactly what I need!

Comment: Please note that this answer is outdated. This is indeed supported in serverless framework now as I explain in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64867520/1495198).

Comment: @VivekMaharajh I don't have time to test this, but I've upvoted your answer and edited mine to reference yours. Thanks